# how to calculate $e^{tA}$ with $tr(A)=0$ and invertible matrix $A\in{M_{2}(\mathbb{R})}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

> How to calculate $e^{tA}$ with $tr(A)=0$ and invertible matrix $A\in{M_{2}(\mathbb{R})}$?

By Cayley-Hamilton, we can get
$$A^2+|A|I=0$$
Then we calculate the non-zero eigenvalues
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{}
            \pm\sqrt{\det{}A}i & |A|>0\\
            \pm\sqrt{-\det{}A} & |A|<0\\
\end{array}\right.$$
so it exists an invertible matrix $P$ for which
$$P^{-1}\exp{(tA)}P=\left\{ \begin{array}{}
            {\rm diag}(e^{t\sqrt{\det{}A}i},e^{-t\sqrt{\det{}A}i}) & |A|>0\\
            {\rm diag}(e^{t\sqrt{-\det{}A}},e^{-t\sqrt{-\det{}A}}) & |A|<0\\
\end{array}\right.$$

but how to  calculate $e^{tA}$ with the result
$$e^{tA}=\left\{ \begin{array}{}
            \cos(t\sqrt{\det {A}})I+\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{\det{}A})}{\sqrt{\det{A}}}A & |A|>0\\
            \cosh(t\sqrt{-\det {A}})I+\frac{\sinh(t\sqrt{-\det{}A})}{\sqrt{-\det{A}}}A & |A|<0\\
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: The word is *calculate*

Comment: Sry, I've edited it.

Comment: $e^{tA}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^nA^n}{n!}$. Split as $\sum_{n\text{ even}}+\sum_{n\text{ odd}}$, and substitute $A^2=(-\det A)I$ in $(A^2)^k$ and $(A^2)^kA.$

Comment: 1) You should say that your matrices are $2 \times 2$. Your calculations are no longer true above dim. 2 2) In the last expressions you need to use an $I$(Identity) matrix  : $\cos (t \sqrt{\det A})\color{red}{I}$.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it. There is actually a typo mistake.@JeanMarie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d=\sqrt{|\det A|}$.

You have
$$
e^{tdi}=\cos td+i \sin td.
$$
So
\begin{align}
e^{tA}&=P\,\begin{bmatrix}\cos td+i \sin td&0\\0& \cos td-i \sin td\end{bmatrix}\,P^{-1}\\[0.2cm]
&=P\,\begin{bmatrix}\cos td&0\\0& \cos td\end{bmatrix}\,P^{-1}
+i P\begin{bmatrix}\sin td&0\\0& -\sin td\end{bmatrix}\,P^{-1}\\[0.2cm]
&=\cos td\,I+i\,\frac{\sin td}{d}\,P\begin{bmatrix}d&0\\0&-d \end{bmatrix}\,P^{-1}\\[0.2cm]
&=\cos td\,I+i\,\frac{\sin td}{d}\,A.
\end{align}
The case with $e^{td}$ is similar, now with the hyperbolic sine and cosine.

Comment: never been served hyperbolic wine

Comment: You should try it! :D